# скрытое поле от СПАМА - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайт постоянно летит спам в комменты. С WP знаком мало (я так понимаю, что делаться должно все в `function.php`, чтобы после обновы не слетело), поэтому подскажите как добавить скрытое поле для формы комментов, а т.к спам этот не конкретно идет по моему сайту (на многие рассылка идет)?

Comment: Если не знакомы с WP, то лучше не вмешиваться в functions.php. Плагин Akismet стоит? Его обычно достаточно.

Comment: я не знаком  с WP, но я знаком с php.  Мне нужно просто знать, как там в этом движке  вставляются поля, через какую функцию и синтаксис. 

Плагины - лишнее .

Comment: Вам все равно придется свой плагин создавать, чтобы при обновлении wp не править файлы.

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian, 1. плагины не лишнее -  а [правильный способ кастомизации функционала](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9). Как раз для того, "чтобы после обновы не слетело". 2 Акисмет действительно хорошо помогает от спама. 3. Если не акисмет, то придётся писать свой плагин. Знаний php тут не достаточно. Нужны знания ВП поглубже, чем у домохозяйки.

Comment: >(я так понимаю, что делаться должно все в function.php   
Если  `function.php`, то не ВП, а темы. Причем [дочерней](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)

Comment: Ответ-то я написал, но все равно - добиться такого качества фильтрации, как у akismet, такими примитивными действиями не получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать хук `comment_form_default_fields`.

В `functions.php` [дочерней темы](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html) добавьте примерно такой код:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'add_field' );
function add_field( $fields ){
    $fields['my_hidden_field'] = '<p class="comment-form-my-hidden">' . '<label for="my-hidden">' . 'My hidden field' . '</label> ' .
                '<input id="my_hidden_field" name="my_hidden_field" type="hidden" value="" size="30" /></p>',';
    return $fields;
}
```

Это создаст дополнительное поле в форме комментариев, которое вы потом можете обрабатывать самостоятельно или анализировать комментарий с помощью фильтра `pre_comment_approved`.

```
add_filter( 'pre_comment_approved', 'filter_function_name_11', 10, 2 );
function filter_function_name_11( $approved, $commentdata ){
    // проанализировать комментарий и
    // вернуть 0, 1 или 'spam'

    return $approved;
}
```